# Can't open rails console with Railsinstaller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I'm stuck several hours with this problem. I can't run `rails c` in Windows with Railsinstaller environment.

I tried both `ruby 1.9.3` and `ruby 2.0.0`.

This is the error I get, when I `rails new console_test; cd console_test; rails c`.

```
$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.2)
Switch to inspect mode.
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rb-readline-0.5.1/lib/rbreadline.rb:6083:in `delete': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rb-readline-0.5.1/lib/rbreadline.rb:6083:in `alloc_history_entry'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rb-readline-0.5.1/lib/rbreadline.rb:6116:in `add_history'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rb-readline-0.5.1/lib/readline.rb:368:in `<<'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in load_history'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb:91:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb:91:in `block in load_history'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb:90:in `open'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb:90:in `load_history'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb:80:in `extended'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb:21:in `extend'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb:21:in `init_save_history'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb:44:in `save_history='
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/context.rb:91:in `initialize'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb.rb:429:in `new'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb.rb:429:in `initialize'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb.rb:385:in `new'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb.rb:385:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I added `gem 'rb-readline', '~> 0.5.1', require: false` in `Gemfile`, but it doesn't solve the problem.

I downloaded `readline5.dll` from [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/readline.htm), and rename `readline.dll` and move to a directory same as ruby binary. But it didn't work neither.

What can I do anything else to solve the problem?

*Edit*

I deleted `C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.0.0` and `~/.gem`, then installed new Railsinstaller.

But `rb-readline` error remained.

I also downloaded and installed `Rubyinstaller` and `Devkit`. Even though `rb-readline` error didn't disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out, cause of this error.

I had a `~/.irbrc` that is like this.

```
require 'irb/ext/save-history'
#History configuration
IRB.conf[:SAVE_HISTORY] = 100
IRB.conf[:HISTORY_FILE] = "#{ENV['HOME']}/.irb-save-history"
```

I simply removed the `.irbrc`, then I can use now `rails console` without problem.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your sollution, but anyone has figured how to fix this problem without removing `SAVE_HISTORY`? I want `irb` to save my history

Answer (score -2):

Did you tried running this command:

```
Tools | Run Rails Console...
```

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood this....Tools is used with Ruby mine so that you can execute commands directly from it.